# App exported with Pyinstaller doesn't run: '[99474] Error loading Python lib'

Tags: tkinter, export, pyinstaller, python-3.11

I made a simple productivity timer app using tkinter and pillow. It has a couple of images and one sound effect and runs fine in my IDE. I wanted to export it so others could try it out.

When I open the unix file, this is the error I get (the script is called 'NWS.py'):

```
Dominics-MBP:~ <PATHTOFILE>/build/NWS/NWS ; exit;
[99474] Error loading Python lib '<PATHTOFILE>/build/NWS/Python': dlopen: 
dlopen(<PATHTOFILE>/build/NWS/Python, 0x000A): tried: 
'<PATHTOFILE>/build/NWS/Python' (no such file),
 '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/<PATHTOFILE>/build/NWS/Python' (no such file), 
 '<PATHTOFILE>/build/NWS/Python' (no such file)
logout
```

I navigated to the file directory and used 'pyinstaller NWS.py'
I also tried the commands '--onefile', '-w' and my path to Python.
An app gets created (120MB) and a package (5MB), but neither of them open.

I tried moving the .wav file for the sound effect into the same folder.
I checked if my IDE and my terminal are running the same version of Python and they're both on 3.11.2

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is it possible that you hard coded paths into your application? Can you provide your source?

Comment: I didn't, no. There's one png file, one jpeg and one .wav, but all of them are in the project folder. I'm running Pyinstaller 5.9.0. 
I tried using os.path.join, creating a separate 'assets' folder, but launching the unix file, it still couldn't find the .wav:
"[4680] Failed to execute script 'NWS'
due to unhandled exception: [Errno] No such file or directory: 'end.wav'"

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was
a) importing sys, importing os
and b) putting this if statement at the top of my script:

```
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    application_path = sys._MEIPASS
else:
    application_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

and then assigning my resource files like so:

```
picture_jpeg_path = os.path.join(application_path, 'picture.jpeg')
sound_wav_path = os.path.join(application_path, 'sound.wav')
```

then I just renamed my .jpeg and my .wav within the script with the new names above. Application runs fine now.